# Prestashop convert tpl to php

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem, I have a code in smarty but I have to put it in a php file in one of the module, but I have no idea how to do it.
It's me in this module can receive m.in the total width of the package.

{$db = Db::getInstance()}

```
            {$flag = 0}
            {foreach $products as $product}
                {$flag = $flag + 1}
                {assign var='productId' value=$product.id_product}

                {*Height*}
                {$sql = "SELECT height FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = $productId"}
                {assign var='height' value=$db->getValue($sql)}
                {*/Height*}

                {*Width*}
                {$sql = "SELECT width FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = $productId"}
                {assign var='width' value=$db->getValue($sql)}
                {*/Width*}

                {*DEPTH*}
                {$sql = "SELECT depth FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = $productId"}
                {assign var='depth' value=$db->getValue($sql)}
                {*/DEPTH*}

                {assign var='quantity' value=$product.cart_quantity-$quantityDisplayed}
                {assign var='capacity' value=$height*$width*$depth}

                {$Arrayquantity.$flag = $quantity}
                {$ArrayCapacity.$flag = $capacity}
                {$weight = $cart->getTotalWeight()|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'|number_format:2}
            {/foreach}

            {$capacity = 0}
            {foreach $ArrayCapacity as $key => $value}
                {$capacity = $capacity + $value*$Arrayquantity[$key]/1000000}
            {/foreach}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to execute SQL queries within smarty? You should do that in the module’s PHP file, and then pass the variables over to your template to output them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and if you could write me a look like they have the sql query in php file?

Comment: Search for `ArrayCapacity` in you cache folder, you may find this template compiled to php file. However, it's still probably not gonna help you much.

Comment: In cach unfortunately there is no such thing, I looked through all the folders and found nothing.
Does anyone have maybe some other idea?

Comment: I have problem in save in php                 {$weight = $cart->getTotalWeight()|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'|number_format:2}

Answer (score 1):

Oh, man, you don't really get how it works. You need to check how controllers assign variables to templates, how {assign} work in Smarty... this whole code should be in controller or in your module and you need to assign values to view using $this->context->smarty->assign.

I highly recommend you to look on few default modules to see how it work.